# Age of Empires II: Problems saving in the Scenario Editor

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I have found an extremely annoying problem with the scenario editor in Age of Empires II. When I open a previously saved map in the editor, I sometimes discover that the last minutes or hours of work is gone, even though I am sure I saved the changes before exiting the editor the last time. In other words, it is like I didn't save the last minutes (or hours) of work before quitting the editor the last time.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit). Is this a known problem? If so, is there a solution, or, at least, a way to make sure no data is lost?

Answer (score 1):

The scenario won't save if it is in use by another program without telling you.
Another reason could be a too long scenario name. There are numerous issues for multiplayer games concerning the length of the file name or using the same file name for a different new game.

What always works is saving the scenario to a new file name, except for obvious reasons like diskspace shortage and the like.

Also make sure you run AOE II as admin to prevent nasty issues with file rights.